# How can I tell how many rows or objects are in my table using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I tell how many rows or objects are in my table using MySQL Workbench ? 
I think I have 9000 items, but since I can only select 1000 as my limit in Workbench. Now I am not sure whether or not my data is there.

[image]

Comment: Select "Table Inspector" from that list to analyze the table. The table inspector has an entry titled "Table rows:".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename;
```

[image]

I should note that not every table engine can provide exact results without a `WHERE` part. InnoDB in particular. But it should be enough to just do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE some_column IS NOT NULL;
```

On a `NOT NULL` defined column, for example.

Comment: Keep in mind you can disable the limit (e.g. via Preferences) to get all rows. However the count() aggregate function is better (no unnecessary data transfer).

Answer (score 0):

This will provide us more detail about the table.
Right click, and click **Table Inspector**

[image]

According to my situation, the fourth line is exactly what I want to know.

**Table rows : 34165**

[image]